# why c++wt is not integrated with ExtJs 3.x ? and how is it possible to integrate it with that?

Tags: c++, extjs, wt

I just wondering why wt (the WebToolkit for c++) is not integrated with ExtJs 3.x whereas it is still using extJs 2.x.

and how is it possible to integrated it with the updated version of extjs I want to use some updated widget out of extjs 3.0 with the help of wt but unfortunately there is no chance :(

regards.

Comment: Somebody needs to do the work.  As with any Open Source project, that somebody could be you.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that they're not so happy about Ext JS style widgets anymore, and prefer to use their own widgets.

I think it's the answer to most open source support questions. It's like nobody that's working on the project is interested in upgrading all the code to the latest version; if you really want it, do it yourself, or pay someone :)

There is some interest in it and more info here: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=26058692

The summary there for not upgrading is basically:

> No, I think they're not ..  some
>   boring  licencing  stuff  no one
>   actually cares about  except for  the
>   Emweb guys :) And the fact that ExtJS
>   is getting really buggy :-)